# Could somebody create the tag synonym olfaction <- olfactory

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Somebody with the privilege should create the tag synonym [olfaction](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olfaction) <- [olfactory](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olfactory) (I don't have the tag count to do so). I could retag all Qs that use "olfactory" but this would bring them all to the top of the activity cue.

Just a small step in a well-needed tag cleanup...

Comment: It only takes 5 rep in that tag to create a synonym. Point me to one of your (preferably good :) ) answers in it and I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: Dont think I have any, there are only one user with >5 in olfactory. I was just looking over the tag list, and spotted this duplicate. This should probably be done by a moderator.

Comment: Anyone with [>= 1250 rep](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) and at least a score of 5 in the tag can.

Comment: yes I know - the problem is that nobody has >5 in olfaction and only one has >5 in olfactory. @terdon

Comment: In general, how are issues like this one best handled? Should the moderators remove/synonymize irrelevant and duplicate tags? The system to create and vote on tag synonyms doesn't seem very useful, at least for beta sites.

Comment: @terdon It is almost impossible on a small site for the community to create a tag synonym due to the high barriers and the extremely low visibility of tag synonym suggestions. It is far easier for a moderator to simply create the synonym.

Comment: I am a little confused about the synonym recommendations: How do I upvote a suggested synonym ?

Comment: @WYSIWYG Go to the main tag synonym page (not the suggested synonym), and you will see up/down vote arrows for the suggested synonyms, see e.g. http://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/dna/synonyms. You will only be allowed to vote if you have an answer score of 5+.

Answer (score 3):

I've merged the two tags, I didn't create a synonym as I don't think this would provide any advantage. [olfaction](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olfaction) will be the only choice presented to users.

Comment: Fair enough, and thanks. Was I wrong about suggested synonyms entering the review queue? It's true we don't have enough reviewers though so the point may be mute.

Comment: @terdon There is no review queue for them as far as I know

Comment: Ah, only for tag wiki edits then. OK, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Agree that synonym is not really needed since its the same term (not olfaction <- smell).

Comment: Feel free to do herpetology <- reptiles as well. What should we do about the [suggested synonyms](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) in general? At the moment they are pending with basically no voting going on.

Comment: @fileunderwater I'm rather skeptical about most of the suggested synonyms, I'm not sure those are a good idea and pretty much each would need a meta discussion before I would feel comfortable to actually approve or decline them.

Comment: @MadScientist Agree that some need a meta discussion.